# What does " : " after Board.fromDatabase(DataSnapshot snapshot) mean. I want to undestand how " : " works here and what is it. If possible by exmaple

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, operator-keyword

import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class Board { String key; String subject; String body;

Board(this.subject, this.body);

Board.fromDatabase(DataSnapshot snapshot) : key = snapshot.key, subject = snapshot.value["subject"], body = snapshot.value["body"];

toJson() { return { "subject": subject, "body": body, }; } }